# Is it a good practice to have clientid as first field in the table, thus making a composite key in lieu of faster fetch

Tags: mysql, rdbms

My Scenario is to have multiple clients and have their data segregated by client id. To me it appears having client id as the first field in almost all the tables will make the primary index and the data segregation faster.

Sample SQL(MySQL)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS client ( 
  client_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  client_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
  created  DATETIME NOT NULL, 
  modified TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
 )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff (
  client_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  staff_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
  created DATETIME NOT NULL,
  modified TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (client_id, staff_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES client(client_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

bill_master etc.
```

Comment: I'm not sure there is a "first" field, at least not with regard to the position of the column.  The primary key in `client` is the `client_id`, because you defined it that way.  Similarly, the primary key in `staff` is the composite of the `client_id` and `staff_id`.  This composite key would make sense if you plan to do a lot of queries involving both these columns.

Comment: I mean to ask there could be two ways to create table, like one is - creating staff table with only primary key staffid(instead of making a composite key clientid+staffid) and making client id just as foreign key, the other one is what i have made as posted above?

Comment: based on two architectures which select query will be faster? select * from staff where staffid = "" and clientid = "" or select * from staff where clientid = "" and staffid = "".

Answer (score 1):

In this cases you can define index on your client_id field and with this approach it will be fast in MySQL

```
ALTER TABLE `staff` ADD INDEX(`client_id`);
```

Comment: I mean to ask there could be two ways to create table, like one is - creating staff table with only primary key staffid(instead of making a composite key clientid+staffid) and making client id just as foreign key, the other one is what i have made as posted above?......based on two architectures which select query will be faster? select * from staff where staffid = "" and clientid = "" or select * from staff where clientid = "" and staffid = "".